# How to fix Mysql error "Status change detected: running" in XAMPP localhost

Tags: mysql, xampp

MySQL suddenly not starting from last 2 days in XAMPP localhost

I tried by changing the PORT number and delete the ibdata1 file. but none of these are worked for me. Below is the error showing in PHPmyadmin

MySQL said: 
Documentation
Cannot connect: invalid settings.

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
>    Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
>
> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
>    phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Error showing in XAMPP:
Status change detected: running

Please help me to resolve this. Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Comment: _No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it_ Are you sure that MySQL Server has been started?

Comment: Look at the MySQL Error log, and if that does not help, look at the Windows Event Viewer for messages from MYSQL